# WCF Rest service and protobuf-net

Tags: rest, wcf, protobuf-net

I followed this link.

[https://www.drdobbs.com/windows/working-with-protobuf-wcf-services/240159282][1]

This link basically shows how to use protobuf-net with WCF service for serialization. My requirement is to use WCF rest with WebGet and WebInvoke options. It doesn't work with this and I always get data at client side in xml serialization and not protobuf. I then went to countless links on here and other sites which claims working WCF + Protobuf but without WCF rest.

There was an information about developing own mediaformator for protobuf but the interface was in WCF preview (2011) and never made it to .net 4.6 I am using.

Am I missing something obvious here or protobuf will simply doesn't work with WCF rest?

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on this answer here [WCF protobuf endpoint 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919691/wcf-protobuf-endpoint-400-bad-request), I could make Protobuf-net working but with a separate endpoint. It also has an issue with uri template for parameters. And also content negotiation is not possible this way as I can't change response type based on the client's accept header. After that I had a look at https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net/ServiceModel/ProtoEndpointBehavior.cs and can see that it also swaps the default datacontract serializer with proto one. Looks like multiple serializer cannot exist on the same endpoint for content negotiation this way.

Answer (score 0):

(speaking in terms of what is directly in the protobuf-net library)

I haven't specifically targeted WCF REST. At the serialization level it should work fine, but I have no idea what is required to hook it into any particular framework / implementation there. It isn't a scenario I've had call for.

Currently, gRPC seems to be getting more love than WCF, so we have full gRPC support.

If there's something I can do to enable WCF REST, then fine - but it isn't a topic I've researched.

Comment: Yes Marc. In fact I have gone through your one of the answer on the similar question where you suggest this mediaformator approach with MVC library. But as I found out, it has never made it to WCF. I see that Protobuf-net provides behavior extension for WCF which I can use in WCF endpoint configuration. Just that I don't see the effect of it for rest operations. I am unfortunately tied up with existing limitations of using WCF rest only and not newer stack like mvc core or gRPC.